# Merge Two Api's from JsonPlaceholder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I'm new to coding and I am in the process of building a blog app. I am using axios to make api calls to Jsonplaceholder. I'm trying to get to map a div that renders a title, description, and name, but I keep getting an error. Any ideas on how to merge the api calls or even a better way to code this?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import '../Styles/content.css'

class Content extends React.Component {
  state ={
    posts: [],
    users: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=10&_limit=10')
    .then(resp => resp.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({posts: data})
      console.log(this.state.posts)
    }).then(
      axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(resp => resp.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({users: data})
      console.log(this.state.users)
    })
    )    
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='contentContainer'>
        {this.state.posts.map(post => (
          <div className='blogs'key={post.id}>
            <div className='blogsPost'>
              <p className='postTitle'>{post.title}</p>
              <p className='postbody'>{post.body}</p>
            </div>
            {this.state.users.filter(user => (
              <div className='blogsUsers'>
                <p>{user.name}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Content
```

Comment: Can you provider content of console.log or error message?

Comment: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, username, email, address, phone, website, company}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in div (at Content.js:31)
    in div (at Content.js:29)
    in Content (at Homepage.js:12)
    in div (at Homepage.js:10)
    in Unknown (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:11)
    in div (at App.js:10)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you wanna find a user who posted the blog content and render, but i guess it will be your solution.

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    users: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?_start=10&_limit=10")
      .then(resp => resp.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ posts: data });
        console.log(this.state.posts);
      })
      .then(
        axios
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
          .then(resp => resp.data)
          .then(data => {
            this.setState({ users: data });
            console.log(this.state.users);
          })
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className="contentContainer">
        {this.state.posts.map(post => {
          const { userId } = post;
          return (
            <div className="blogs" key={post.id}>
              <div className="blogsPost">
                <p className="postTitle">{post.title}</p>
                <p className="postbody">{post.body}</p>
              </div>
              {this.state.users.map(user => {
                if (user.id === userId) {
                  return (
                    <div key={user.id} className="blogsUsers">
                      <p>{user.name}</p>
                    </div>
                  );
                } else {
                  return null;
                }
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Content;
```